# Running 2 async tasks with grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, gruntjs

I am working on a small node project and I use coffeescript and less for client-side code. I am trying to set up my development environment using grunt. I've implemented custom grunt task for running server like this:

```
start = require './start' #just a function to start express.js application
grunt.registerTask 'server', 'Starting server', ->
    grunt.log.write 'Preparing server to start'
    done = do @async
    start (err) ->
        grunt.log.write "server running at localhost:4000"
```

I also want to run the "watch" task using grunt-contrib-watch plugin:

```
grunt.initConfig
    watch:
        coffee:
            files: ['public/coffee/**/*.coffee']
            tasks: ['coffee']
        jade:
            files: ['public/jade/**/*.jade']
            tasks: ['jade']
        less:
            files: ['public/less/**/*.less']
            tasks: ['less']
```

The question is: How to make this two tasks (watch and server) run simultaneously? I want to  have a server up and running and don't want to reload it every time some client-side code is changed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prefix it to your watch tasks, and get rid of the `done = do @async` inside the server task.

`tasks: ['server', 'coffee']`

You want to specify an option in your Grunt configuration for the server task to be "long-running" or not.  Then you can call `@async` only if you need it to be long running (without the watch task).

Comment: This doesn't work because the server task doesn't end, thus never giving control back to the watch task.

Comment: Yes it does end; as I explain in my answer you remove the async() call which allows the task to end, and then conditionally add it back based on an option.

Comment: I'm confused. He wants the server to be always long-running, and he wants the watch to be long-running and he wants them both running at the same time from a single grunt call. Is that what you're achieving here? Doesn't look like it

Answer (score 8):

You can run two or more tasks at the same time using any of these two packages :

1. [grunt-parallel](https://github.com/iammerrick/grunt-parallel)
2. [grunt-concurrent](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue of not being able to launch both watch and connect server from a grunt task.

To solve the problem, I started the server as background process using grunt-exec in my Gruntfile

The ampersand (&) at the end of `grunt connect:preview &` is what starts the server as a background process.

```
,exec: {
  start_server: {
    command: 'grunt connect:preview &'
  }
}
```

And then register the grunt task like this

```
grunt.registerTask('preview', ['clean:preview', 'template', 'exec', 'watch' ]);
```

There's got to be a better way to do this, but so far it's the best I could think of.

Comment: I am using grunt-shell instead of grunt-exec and the `&` seems to have no effect.