# Is there a way to make the qunit grunt task run tests in parallel?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, phantomjs, qunit, grunt-contrib-qunit

[The qunit plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-qunit) works great, but I've got so many tests (some of which are a little slow) that it takes 14 seconds to run all of them.  I think this time could be cut in half if my tests could be run in parallel.

As an attempt, I tried creating two html files with my tests, but the qunit plugin ran them sequentially.  [There's already a feature request](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-qunit/issues/53) asking for this so it's probably not possible. But I'm hoping there's a PhantomJS expert out there that knows a way to do it by passing in PhantomJS arguments.

If this is not possible in qunit but it is possible in another testing framework/grunt plugin, I might be willing to switch to it over this.  So I might consider, "use X framework instead" as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running 2 async tasks with grunt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766538/running-2-async-tasks-with-grunt)